# Como presenta el valor de la llave foranea

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

## Como modificar la salida del API REST Framework

Usando el mismo ejemplo de la [documentación](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) quiero presentar el **nombre del álbum** en lugar de su ID (la cual viene siendo la FK hacia el álbum).

Salida:

```
{
    'album': 11,
    'order': 'Low',
    'title': '1: Sunflower',
    'duration': '1232'
}
...
```

Resultado deseado:

```
{
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'order': 'Low',
    'title': '1: Sunflower',
    'duration': '1232'
}
...
```

Es decir, quiero el registro con el **título del álbum** no su ID (llave foránea).

No quiero modificar el método `__str__` del modelo. Ocupo la salida de todos los campos para otra actividad.

#### Con que se probo

- Con este [función](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) `SlugRelatedField`
- Personalizando el campo de la relación como lo indica el [ejemplo](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soy nuevo en *Django Rest Framework*, pero según he leído la documentación, habría 3 formas de hacerlo.

#### 1. Campos relacionales personalizados

```
class AlbumNameRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.album_name
```

Supongo que el campo que quieres mostrar es `album_name`, en dado caso no sea así, remplaza el atributo (`value.<field_name>`).

Tu serializador:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumNameRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = [..., 'album']
```

Y listo, obtendrás el resultado deseado.

#### 2. Utilizar el campo [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)

> *"`SlugRelatedField` puede usarse para representar el objetivo de la relación utilizando un campo en el objetivo."*

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field = 'album_name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = [..., 'album']
```

Según la documentación no es de mala practica que el campo del objetivo de la relación no sea estrictamente un `SlugField`, esto lo digo porque ellos mismo utilizaron de ejemplo un campo `title` que era un `CharField`. Con esto de igual manera obtendrás el resultado deseado.

#### 3. Especificando el argumento [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) en un campo (actualización)

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = serializers.CharField(source = 'album.album_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = [..., 'album']
```

> ***Argumento [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):***
>
> *El nombre del atributo que se usará para completar el campo. Puede ser
> un método que solo toma un `self` argumento, como
> `URLField(source='get_absolute_url')`, o puede usar notación punteada
> para atravesar atributos, como **`EmailField(source='user.email')`**.*
>
> ***...***

Evidentemente el *campo de serializador* debe ser acorde al tipo de campo de la instancia relacionada. Y en mi opinión, esta es la mejor opción.

---

#### Actualización:

Estos deberían ser los modelos que estas utilizando:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['album', 'order']
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

Ya actualice el código de acuerdo a dichos modelos. Por otra parte, el porque no sale el campo, es porque el campo debe llamarse igual a la relación (me olvide XD).

Comment: Acabo de probar ambos no sale el campo, lo salta `{ 'order': 'Low', 'title': '1: Sunflower',  'duration': '1232'}` no hay error, ni nada simplemente lo salta

Comment: @Cristian acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, ya esta solucionado el problema, échale un vistaso.

Comment: como mencione no quiero modificar la funcion `__str__`  la uso para otras operaciones

Comment: ¿En que momento tienes que modificar dicho método? Las alternativas que propongo en mi respuesta no requieren modificar dicho método, ademas en ningún momento propongo utilizar el campo [`StringRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield), por si las dudas...

Comment: en la actualizacion esta respondiendo a eso

Comment: No... te refieres al nombre de la relación? si es así, no tiene nada que ver con el método `__str__`...

Comment: y si eso ah sido ocupar el mismo nombre de la llave foranea, no crear uno diferente, gracias