# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un dato a través de llaves foráneas (Django)?

Tags: python, angular, django, postgresql, djangorestframework

Buenas estoy realizando un proyecto don angular y Django donde utilizo PostgreSQL como base de datos, estoy intentando listar los usuarios en un tabla, pero los campos `sexo` y `tipoidentificacion` que son llaves foráneas me muestra los id(1 y 2), así como muestro a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación les dejos los archivos de Django y Angular que estoy utilizando:

**Archivos Django:**

Archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Sexo(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class TipoIdentificacion(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30) 

class Persona(models.Model):
  nombres = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  tipoidentificacion = models.ForeignKey(TipoIdentificacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  sexo = models.ForeignKey(Sexo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  direccion = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from clientes_app.models import Persona, Sexo, TipoIdentificacion
from clientes_app.serializers import PersonaSerializer, SexoSerializer, TipoIdentificacionSerializer

class PersonaLista (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Persona.objects.all
  serializer_class = PersonaSerializer

class SexoLista (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Sexo.objects.all()
  serializer_class = SexoSerializer

class TipoIdentificacionLista (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = TipoIdentificacion.objects.all()
  serializer_class = TipoIdentificacionSerializer
```

Archivo `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from clientes_app.models import Persona, Sexo, TipoIdentificacion

class PersonaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Persona
    fields = '__all__'

class SexoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Sexo
    fields = '__all__'

class TipoIdentificacionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = TipoIdentificacion
    fields = '__all__'
```

**Archivos Angular:**

Archivo `sevicio.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UsuariosI } from './../../interfaces/usuarios/usuarios'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuariosService {

  URL_API = 'http://localhost:8000';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  obtenerUsuarios(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.URL_API}/persona/`);
  }
}
```

Archivo `listar-usuarios.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuariosService } from 'src/app/services/usuarios/usuarios.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listar-usuarios',
  templateUrl: './listar-usuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listar-usuarios.component.css']
})
export class ListarUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {
  usuarios:any = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['identificacion', 'tipoidentificacion', 'nombres', 'apellidos', 'sexo', 'telefono', 'direccion'];
  dataSource:any;

  constructor(private usuariosService:UsuariosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mostrarUsuarios();
  }  

  mostrarUsuarios(){
    this.usuariosService
      .obtenerUsuarios()
        .subscribe(
          res =>{
            this.dataSource = res;
            console.log(this.dataSource)
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Son llaves foráneas, así que es normal que se muestre el ID, a menos que especifiques el campo.

Entonces tu serializador `PersonaSerializer`, debería ser así:

```
class PersonaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tipoidentificacion = serializers.CharField(source = 'tipoidentificacion.nombre')
    sexo = serializers.CharField(source = 'sexo.nombre')

    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        fields = '__all__'
```

Con el argumento [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) especificamos el atributo de la relación, toma en cuenta que las relaciones como tal en Python, son en pocas palabras atributos.

Hay varias maneras de hacer esto, si estas mas interesado en las otras formas, te sugiero revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376451/como-presenta-el-valor-de-la-llave-foranea/376476#376476) (evidentemente esta es la mejor).

Y los datos serializados serán algo así:

```
>>> PersonaSerializer(...).data
{'id': 1, ..., 'tipoidentificacion': '...', 'sexo': '...', ...}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias, con tu respuesta fue mas que suficiente para solucionar mi problema, disculpa si fue una pregunta muy obvia, pero en realidad no sabia como hacerlos, solo estoy empezando a utilizar python y django.

Comment: Tranquilo no pasa nada y un gusto ayudarte broda! xD